# Why does every GraphQL schema have a root query and mutation type?

Tags: graphql

Why does every GraphQL schema require a root `query` and `mutation` type? It seems like needless boilerplate. Do schemas ever need this written differently? Shouldn't this bit of boilerplate be obvious?

```
schema {
  query:Query
  mutation:Mutation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I too was Googling this, and ended up manually searching the graphql-js source where there is [this comment](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/2592e1293c650eef1e06760ce85fb29f125568b9/src/utilities/schemaPrinter.js#L123):

```
/**
 * GraphQL schema define root types for each type of operation. These types are
 * the same as any other type and can be named in any manner, however there is
 * a common naming convention:
 *
 *   schema {
 *     query: Query
 *     mutation: Mutation
 *   }
 *
 * When using this naming convention, the schema description can be omitted.
 */
```

Comment: So you could call `Query` `Qry`? What's the utility?

Comment: @RyanMarsh well, naming things is hard... personally I went with the convention.